# Can the 'wild' modifier be applied to non-armor items, such as enchanted cloaks or jewelry?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, dnd-3e, wild-shape

D&D 3.x has the "wild" modifier specified for armor and shields that causes its base AC bonus and any enhancement-type bonus (such as magical AC bonuses and/or ability score bonuses) to be applied while the wearer is wildshaped.  As per the D&D 3.5 SRD:

> The wearer of a suit of armor or a shield with this ability preserves his 
>   armor bonus (and any enhancement bonus) while in a wild shape. Armor and 
>   shields with this ability usually appear to be made covered in leaf patterns. 
>   While the wearer is in a wild shape, the armor cannot be seen.

Can this modifier also be applied to other items that grant enhancement bonuses (say a ring that grants +1 Wisdom) so that they continue to grant this bonus while the wearer is wildshaped?  Or are enhancement-granting items treated as continuing to grant their bonuses while the wearer is wildshaped to begin with?  Also, are there any changes on this front between D&D 3.0 and D&D 3.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Officially, in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* as per the *Player's Handbook* (2012), the druid's supernatural ability [wild shape](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#wildShape) works like the special ability [alternate form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#alternateForm) except when wild shape *doesn't* work like alternate form, such as in this case:

> Any gear worn or carried by the druid melds into the new form and becomes nonfunctional. (*PH* 37)

In *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* the special ability *wild shape* (in italics!) was revised so many times that I have no idea how it ended up working, but I don't think I'm going too far out on a limb by saying *Not very well.* That said...

## The magic armor and shield special ability [*wild*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm#wild) is only for armor and shields...

Although, I suppose, the special ability could, as per the rules on page 130 of the *Arms and Equipment Guide*, also be put on [*bracers of armor*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#bracersofArmor) (*DMG* 250) (1,000+ gp; 1 lb.), the magic armor and shield special ability [*wild*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm#wild) (*DMG* 219) (+3 bonus; 0 lbs.) says that

> The wearer of a suit of armor or a shield with this ability preserves his armor bonus (and any enhancement bonus) while in a wild shape. Armor and shields with this ability usually appear to be made covered in leaf patterns. While the wearer is in a wild shape, the armor cannot be seen.

This special ability is better in *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* (where it first appeared in *Masters of the Wild* at the same price) where shields grant an armor bonus; in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* the DM must house rule that *wild* shields grant their wielders their *shield* and enhancement bonuses. (I *know*, right?)<sup>1</sup>

### ...Other items get a *wilding clasp* or stuffed in a *druid's satchel*

The *wilding clasp* (*MIC* 190) (4,000 gp; 0 lbs.) in *3.5* terms

> can be attached to **any item worn on the body**. When so worn, a clasp prevents the worn item from melding into your new form when you use wild shape (as long as the item could reasonably be worn by the new form). Thus, the item remains fully functional and can be used normally in your new form.

Emphasis mine. The *wilding clasp* is, essentially, unchanged from its original appearance in *Masters of the Wild* for *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition.*

Items the druid doesn't want melded that *aren't* worn or that don't need to be used immediately upon using wild shape should, instead, be stored in a [*druid's satchel*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/53101/8610) (*Dungeon* #92 103) (3,000 gp; 5 lbs.), which was written for *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* and never updated to *3.5* (making it legal in both, but the DM's allowed to update it however he wants for a *3.5* campaign).

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The magic armor special ability *beastskin* (*MIC* 7) (+2 bonus; 0 lbs.) can be substituted for the special ability *wild* at some reduced functionality.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the Wilding Clasp (MiC 190).

It costs 4,000 gp, and can be attached to any piece of gear.  A piece of gear so attached doesn't transform when you wild shape.  You can have as many Wilding Clasps as you can afford, there's no limit to the number of pieces of gear you can keep.