# Piercing DR/magic without using equipment to get DR/magic

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage-reduction

My Character for a 3.5 D&D game is a Barbarian going for the Bear Warrior-War Shaper route. I even took a Fist of The Forest to hope doing some real nice Kung fu Panda stuff. But unfortunately my DM said that UAS and natural weapons do not work together, so I cannot use anything from that level other than the AC bonus and I can't take the level back.

I just wanna ask, since I am not allowed to wear any kind of armour and going on the higher levels now; how do I make my Claw and Bite attack considered magical damage, since most foes have some pretty nasty DR/- later on?  I am aware that having DR/magic actually gives magical natural weapons.

But since I transform, my DM says that everything I have on is morphed and therefore no benefits works.

Does this mean I have to get something obscure like a bracers of beastskin-DR/magic just to get the benefit, or is there a way to do this easier?

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64292/8610) and [related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65418/8610).

Answer (score 3):

Getting DR/magic yourself may or may not work; many sources for PCs explicitly call out that they do not grant piercing DR/magic themselves.

However, as long as you have at least a +1 bonus on your natural weapons, they will count as magical. The easiest way to do that is in core, the [Amulet of Mighty Fists](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#amuletofMightyFists), although the Amulet of Natural Attacks is more flexible and should allow the same results. In either case, a Wilding Clasp (MIC, 4000gp) should allow you to use the item just fine while transformed.

Comment: Thx for the fast answer. i will disgust this with my DM.

Comment: Although im pretty sure he will say that the amulet too is morphed into my "skins" when transformed and therefore not working :P

Comment: oh didnt see the wilding clasp part. this is great :D

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to have someone cast [Magic Fang](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicFang.htm) on you. That lasts a few rounds. If you have a Druid buddy, you can ask him to cast [Greater Magic Fang](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicFangGreater.htm) on you with breakfast each morning. That instead lasts hours/level, and provides a +1 per four caster levels.

The simplest ongoing way would be to have someone cast [Magic Fang](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicFang.htm) and [Permanency](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/permanency.htm) on you. Market price for getting both should be about 3000gp, though you will need to get a 9th level wizard and ranger or druid in the same place.

You can also get Greater Magic Fang + Permanency if you want more numbers in addition to penetrating DR/magic. It then requires an 11th level wizard and costs 3050gp, plus the cost of the Greater Magic Fang.

These options are all core.