# Does 'Wild' armour work for Alternate Form?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wild-shape, armor

Could a creature that doesn't have Wild Shape, but -does- have Alternate Form (Such as a Dragon) use armour with the "wild" property to be able to use this armour in all their forms?

In the question [Preventing gear loss while using Change Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33675/preventing-gear-loss-while-using-change-shape), one of the answers seemed to suggest so. However, Wild Armour specifically mentions Wild Shape, not Alternate Form. Furthermore, while Wild Shape works "like Alternate Form except where mentioned", the same is not necesarily true the other way around.

If this does not work, then what other way might there be for a creature with Alternate Form to wear their armour in every shape they can take?

Answer (score 1):

#### By RAW, probably not

As you mentioned, the armor specifies Wild Shape. So having only the Alternate Form special ability would not qualify.

#### By RAI, probably

In errata, WotC changed Wild Shape to use the Alternate Form mechanics, so now Wild Shape is, more or less, just a specific type of Alternate Form. And it seems awkward to claim the armor special ability somehow knows the type of Alternate Form being used to activate its effect. This was likely an oversight when generating the errata.

#### Other methods to use armor in alternate form:

Have armor created that can be worn in each new form. Only put the correct armor on after changing form. RAW, that's probably the only way.

A better approach, use Bracers of Armor and only change into forms that can use the bracers. Some DMs may require you to take the bracers off before using Alternate Form and putting them on after. Similarly for amulets of natural armor, rings of protection, etc. Use magic to replicate the effects of armor.